# Ginkgo binaries not seen in Mac directories

Tags: go, ginkgo

I have installed ginkgo, but I cannot locate it inside the /Users/user-name/gowork/src/github.com/onsi folder. If I delete the gowork folder, I can see the ginkgo folders within it, in Trash.
ginkgo version returns:
bash: /Users/user-name/gowork/bin/ginkgo: No such file or directory
Could there be a reason why this is happening?

I have tried setting GOPATH variable, but there is no effect.